# Convert items in Vec that match an if-condition to NaN

Tags: rust, iterator, conditional-operator

I have a `Vec<f32>` with zero values that I'd like to convert into `NaN`. Is there a way to do this by modifying the `Vec` in-place with a conditional statement?

This is what I tried so far:

```rust
let mut vector: Vec<f32> = vec![2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, 5.0];
vector
    .iter_mut()
    .for_each(|v| if *v == 0.0 { f32::NAN } else { *v });
println!("{vector:?}");
```

But the compiler is giving me this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/io/mod.rs:8:38
  |
8 |         .for_each(|v| if *v == 0.0 { f32::NAN } else { *v });
  |                       ---------------^^^^^^^^--------------
  |                       |              |
  |                       |              expected `()`, found `f32`
  |                       expected this to be `()`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/io/mod.rs:8:56
  |
8 |         .for_each(|v| if *v == 0.0 { f32::NAN } else { *v });
  |                       ---------------------------------^^--
  |                       |                                |
  |                       |                                expected `()`, found `f32`
  |                       expected this to be `()`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Can someone point out what the proper syntax should be to get a `Vec` with `0` replaced with `NaN`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn’t do any writing:

```
.for_each(|v| if *v == 0.0 { *v = f32::NAN; });
```

More typically:

```
let mut vector: Vec<f32> = vec![2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, -1.0, 5.0];
for v in &mut vector {
    if *v == 0.0 {
        *v = f32::NAN;
    }
}
println!("{vector:?}");
```